# Send Map<K,V> on server(Retrofit 2)

Tags: android, retrofit

Отправляю PUT запрос на сервер при помощи Retrofit 2

```
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})
@PUT("/wp-json/wc/v2/customers/{id}")
Call<RetrofitUserModel> updateUser(@Path("id") String id, @Body Map user, @Query("consumer_key") String consumer_key, @Query("consumer_secret") String consumer_secret);
```

Затем мне необходимо передать в `@Body` объект

```
    {
     "first_name": "James3",
     "billing": {
        "first_name": "James2"
     },
     "shipping": {
       "first_name": "James2"
     }
    }
```

Отправить `"first_name": "James3"` проблем не составляет:

```
Map<String,String> u = new HashMap<String, String>();
u.put("first_name", userName.getText().toString());
```

Но как мне туда добавить объект `billing` с полем `first_name` и `shipping` с полем `first_name`?

Comment: Одним параметров в виде строки весь json, не?

Comment: Мне кажется это не комильфо

Comment: Почему же? Это классическая передача сериализованного объекта.

Comment: Поставьте типом значения мапы Object и передавайте ещё одну мапу